# Python lot of images

Tags: python, pygame, sprite

I want to have an animated backround in `pygame`, and since I didn't find any bette soulutions, I have decided to make it with the help of `sprites`. As far as I know, pygame doesn't support video files, I split the video into frames and made a code like this:

```
class BackgroundAnimator(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self,pos_x,pos_y):
        super().__init__()
        self.sprites = []
        self.is_animating = False
        self.sprites.append(pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load(os.path.join("Textures", "backgroundframe1.jpg")),(WIDTH,HEIGHT)))
```

here I would have to copy this line like 200 times so each frame would be in the sprite

```
        self.current_sprite = 0
        self.image = self.sprites[self.current_sprite]
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.topleft = [pos_x,pos_y]
    
    def animate(self):
        self.is_animating=True

    def update(self):
        if self.is_animating == True:
            self.current_sprite += 0.14
            if self.current_sprite >= len(self.sprites):
                self.current_sprite = 0
            self.image=self.sprites[int(self.current_sprite)]

moving_backgroundsprites = pygame.sprite.Group()
backgroundlocation = BackgroundAnimator(0,0)
```

There is probably a way better solution than this, but I have no idea where to begin. Or how can i load all images without having to paste the same line 200 times, and change the name of the file (so for example backgroundframe1 and then backgroundframe2 and the 3 and so on)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just concatenate the name and the number. The number can be converted to a string with the [`str`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-str) function:

```py
for i in range(1, 100):
    filename = "backgroundframe" + str(i) + ".jpg"
```

Alternatively use [f-strings](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#formatted-string-literals):

```py
for i in range(1, 100):
    filename = f"backgroundframe{i}.jpg"
```

---

e.g.:

```py
class BackgroundAnimator(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self,pos_x,pos_y, filename):
        super().__init__()
        self.sprites = []
        self.is_animating = False
        path = os.path.join("Textures", filename)
        self.sprites.append(pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load(path),(WIDTH,HEIGHT)))
```

```py
no_of_frames = 100 # depends on the number of files
moving_backgroundsprites = pygame.sprite.Group()
for i in range(1, no_of_frames):
    filename = f"backgroundframe{i}.jpg"
    backgroundlocation = BackgroundAnimator(0, 0, filename)
    moving_backgroundsprites.add(backgroundlocation)
```